# Add discrete labels to ggplot2 plot with continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add discrete labels to a `ggplot2` plot with a continuous scale. While there are many questions using `stat_function` (i.e., about [plotting multiple functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085493/ggplot2-add-a-legend-for-several-stat-functions)) and many about how to use different scales, I'm having trouble understanding how to change the scale in this specific instance.

Here is the plot:

```
myfun1 <- function(x) (13.076-96.543)*x + (-44.056 +102.057)*x^2 + (17.856 -42.996)*x^3 + (-2.996  + 7.444)*x^4 + (0.190 -0.450)*x^5 + 100.088 + 75.215 # average vs. lowest
myfun2 <- function(x) 13.076*x -44.056*x^2 + 17.856*x^3 -2.996*x^4 + 0.190*x^5 + 100.088 # lowest
myfun3 <- function(x) (13.076-183.093)*x + (-44.056 +229.447)*x^2 + (17.856 -99.353)*x^3 + (-2.996  + 17.517)*x^4 + (0.190 -1.080)*x^5 + 100.088 + 67.115 # highest vs. lowest

df <- data.frame(x = c(0, 6), y = c(0, 6))

myplot_weekday <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  stat_function(fun = myfun3, aes(color = "Highest")) +
  stat_function(fun = myfun2, aes(color = "Lowest")) +
  stat_function(fun = myfun1, aes(color = "Average")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_colour_manual("Students' Course Grade", values = c("red", "black", "blue")) +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  theme(text=element_text(size= 14, family= "Times")) +
  ylab("Minutes of Videos Watched") +
  xlab("Weekday")
```

[image: weekday plot]

Instead of the continuous labels on the x-axis (0, 2, 4, and 6), I'm trying to add "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", and "Saturday," but I sense I'm approaching this the wrong way.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can set whatever breaks (which will get labels) and corresponding labels that you would like:

```
+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:6,
    labels = paste0(c("Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wednes", "Thurs", "Fri", "Satur"), "day"))
```

Comment: That is straightforward. This warning is displayed: `Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale.` I ignored it, but it seems like when I save the plot, the original (i.e., 0, 2, 4, 6) scale is saved. Any tips about how to save the new (labeled) scale?

Comment: Probably the warning is due to you having `xlab()` separately, better to add `name = "Weekday"` to `scale_x_continuous` and ditch the `xlab`. As for not saving, make sure you re-assign the plot object. If you just do `my_plot_weekday + scale_x_cont...` it will display without modifying the existing plot object. You need `my_plot_weekday <- my_plot_weekday +...` (or add it to the original definition and re-run the assignment).