# ggplot map - adding numeric label on colorbar

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, colorbar, geom-sf

How can I add starting and ending numeric label on color bar ggplot map figure.
For now my code looks like this:

```
my_breaks <- c(1,60000,1200000,24000000,320000000)
ggplot(data = opcine_spojeno) +
geom_sf(aes(fill= HAMAG_Bespovratna_IRI_Pod))+
scale_fill_viridis(trans = "log",
                   name="€",
                   breaks=c(1,60000,1200000,24000000,320000000),
                   labels = scales::label_comma(), 
                   alpha = 3/4) +
 labs(
subtitle = "HAMAG BICRO:Isplaćana bespovratna sredstva u razdoblju 2016-2023",
caption = "Data: HAMAG-BICRO"
 ) +
 theme_minimal()
```

My map looks like this and I would like to add on color bar to the right 1 and 320 000 000, which I tried with piece of code
`my_breaks <- c(1,60000,1200000,24000000,320000000)` 
but it only adds numbers in the middle of the color bar
[image]

Comment: Try with `scale_fill_viridis(..., limits = range(my_breaks))`. Only breaks which fall inside the limits of the scale will be displayed.

Comment: Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59531865/colorbar-guide-with-string-labels-e-g-low-medium-high) might be useful.

Comment: Nope, didn't help: now I removed labels = scales::label_comma() , and I put the follwoing code labels = c("1€","60.000 €","1.200.000 €","24.000.000 €","320.000.000 €"), and it is still not working. I can't belive that you cannot show first and last value on colorbar

Answer (score 1):

Using the nc dataset as a basis. This will also work with your labels list as stated in your comment. I have included other potential options, commented out, that also work:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

# Sample data
set.seed(1)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf")) %>%
  mutate(HAMAG_Bespovratna_IRI_Pod = sample(c(1:3.2e8), 100, replace = TRUE))

my_breaks <- c(1,60000,1200000,24000000,320000000)
code_labels <- c("1€","60.000 €","1.200.000 €","24.000.000 €","320.000.000 €")

ggplot(data = nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill= HAMAG_Bespovratna_IRI_Pod))+
  scale_fill_viridis(trans = "log",
                     name="€",
                     breaks = my_breaks,
                     limits = c(1, 3.2e8),
                     # limits = range(my_breaks),
                     labels = scales::label_comma(),
                     # labels = code_labels,
                     alpha = 3/4) +
  labs(
    subtitle = "HAMAG BICRO:Isplaćana bespovratna sredstva u razdoblju 2016-2023",
    caption = "Data: HAMAG-BICRO"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: result]

Comment: thanks, this does add limits that I want, but it completely changes the viridis color gradient compared to my original map. Everything becomes more lighter and yellow. I don't understand why, because the same limits were before, as when I added your suggested line: "limits = c( 1, 3.2e8)". 
Try the above code without "limits = c( 1, 3.2e8)" and I suppose you will see. Do you get why viridis gradient changes, although the limits are the same?

Comment: I solved it for now this way: I defined breaks a little bit below and above end values, so the breaks are now: my_breaks <- c(5000,60000,1200000,24000000,300000000). Probably the data set did not have max value of 320 M , but around 318/9 M

Comment: @kosk - that would have been my guess and was going to suggest adjusting the breaks. Colouring choropleth maps is as much an art as it is a science. Choosing breaks should always be data-driven (e.g. Jenks natural breaks). Either way, maps lie so it's good to have sound justifications for the methods we use to get them to lie a little less (e.g. the data made me do it).